# Adding views dynamically to ListView item doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have `ListView` which always contains two different child views.

Now I want to work with the first one (position == 0). It's inflated view which contains `ImageView` and `RelativeLayout` (which must hold markers).

After trying to add some view to first item's `RelativeLayout` I saw that they were added but become invisible. Method `RelativeLayout.getChildCount()` return right value but added marker is not visible.

ListView adapter:

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            view = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(act).inflate(R.layout.item_choose_color_picture, parent, false);
            ((ImageView) ((RelativeLayout) view).findViewById(R.id.item_choose_color_image)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            return view;
        case 1:
            view = (ImageView) LayoutInflater.from(act).inflate(R.layout.item_choose_color_palette, parent, false);
            return view;
    }
            return view;
}
```

Layout of first item (item_choose_color_picture):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/item_choose_color_image"
            />

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/item_choose_color_abs"
            >

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
itemRelative = (RelativeLayout) ((RelativeLayout) listView.getChildAt(0)).findViewById(R.id.item_choose_color_abs);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.topMargin = 20;
        layoutParams.leftMargin = 20;
        ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
        view.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.color_marker));
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        itemRelative.addView(view, layoutParams);
```

**UPDATE**

When I do the same with RelativeLayout from main_activity.xml everything works fine. All markers adding to proper places.

Comment: I believe `fill_parent` is deprecated and you should use `match_parent`.

Comment: But this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I didn't expect it to :p that's why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: If you're gonna inflate a different view for position 0 and 1, than the rest of the list, why not just add it in the XML file above the <ListView> ?

Comment: Because, this is a prototype and in future there will be a lot of views like first one.